# What does 江信江疑 mean?

Tags: vocabulary, culture, internet-slang

I came across 江信江疑 in [this tweet about a meme](https://twitter.com/krishraghav/status/1319211079109492736). It clearly has something to do with Jiang Zemin / 江泽民. It seems to be quite commonly used; my guess is that it's something people say on Internet that refers to politicians, or heads of government, and their trustworthiness (or lack of it). But this is just a guess.

What does 江信江疑 actually mean? What's its "back-story"? Is it just used online, or could it be used in spoken Putonghua? Perhaps a few sample sentences would be useful too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm basing my answer on the article [江信江疑是什么意思](http://35vvv.com/wenda/%E6%B1%9F%E4%BF%A1%E6%B1%9F%E7%96%91%E6%98%AF%E4%BB%80%E4%B9%88%E6%84%8F%E6%80%9D) which gives a reasonable explanation.

It's a play on words.  It begins with

> half believing, half doubting / skeptical
> [将信将疑](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E5%B0%86%E4%BF%A1%E5%B0%86%E7%96%91)
> <sub>jiāng​xìn​jiāng​yí</sub>

The line 将信将疑 comes from the poem [吊古战场文](https://zh.m.wikisource.org/zh-hans/%E5%BC%94%E5%8F%A4%E6%88%B0%E5%A0%B4%E6%96%87) by Tang-dynasty poet 李华.

However the meme replaces 将 (​jiāng​) with the surname 江 (Jiāng) which has the same pronunciation and is the family name of [Jiang Zemin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jiang_Zemin) (江泽民).  Then it's added as a caption to memes where 江泽民 looks skeptical, such as:

> [image: An image of 江泽民 looking skeptical captioned 将信将疑]

I'm not really sure how the meme evolved beyond that to what you see on Twitter.